# Cannot connect to Server as Administrator with Impersonate

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010, impersonation

I have to impersonate as administrator to view some network folders, but it doesn't work  beacause the application recognizes the current logged account. This is the class that i used  that I found on the internet :

```
Public Class Impersonator
Private _username As String
Private _password As String
Private _domainname As String

Private _tokenHandle As New IntPtr(0)
Private _dupeTokenHandle As New IntPtr(0)
Private _impersonatedUser As System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext


Public Sub New(ByVal username As String, _
               ByVal password As String)
    Dim nameparts() As String = username.Split(Convert.ToChar("\"))
    If nameparts.Length > 1 Then
        _domainname = nameparts(0)
        _username = nameparts(1)
    Else
        _username = username
    End If
    _password = password
End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal username As String, _
               ByVal password As String, _
               ByVal domainname As String)
    _username = username
    _password = password
    _domainname = domainname
End Sub



Public ReadOnly Property username() As String
    Get
        Return _username
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property domainname() As String
    Get
        Return _domainname
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property currentWindowsUsername() As String
    Get
        Return System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
    End Get
End Property



Public Sub BeginImpersonation()
    'Const LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT As Integer = 0
    'Const LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE As Integer = 2
    Const LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS As Integer = 9
    Const LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50 As Integer = 3
    Const SecurityImpersonation As Integer = 2

    Dim win32ErrorNumber As Integer

    _tokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero
    _dupeTokenHandle = IntPtr.Zero

    If Not LogonUser(_username, _domainname, _password, LOGON32_LOGON_NEW_CREDENTIALS, LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, _tokenHandle) Then
        win32ErrorNumber = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()
        Throw New ImpersonationException(win32ErrorNumber, GetErrorMessage(win32ErrorNumber), _username, _domainname)
    End If

    If Not DuplicateToken(_tokenHandle, SecurityImpersonation, _dupeTokenHandle) Then
        win32ErrorNumber = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetLastWin32Error()

        CloseHandle(_tokenHandle)
        Throw New ImpersonationException(win32ErrorNumber, "Unable to duplicate token!", _username, _domainname)
    End If

    Dim newId As New System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity(_dupeTokenHandle)
    _impersonatedUser = newId.Impersonate()
End Sub

Public Sub EndImpersonation()
    If Not _impersonatedUser Is Nothing Then
        _impersonatedUser.Undo()
        _impersonatedUser = Nothing

        If Not System.IntPtr.op_Equality(_tokenHandle, IntPtr.Zero) Then
            CloseHandle(_tokenHandle)
        End If
        If Not System.IntPtr.op_Equality(_dupeTokenHandle, IntPtr.Zero) Then
            CloseHandle(_dupeTokenHandle)
        End If
    End If
End Sub



Public Class ImpersonationException
    Inherits System.Exception

    Public ReadOnly win32ErrorNumber As Integer

    Public Sub New(ByVal win32ErrorNumber As Integer, ByVal msg As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal domainname As String)
        MyBase.New(String.Format("Impersonation of {1}\{0} failed! [{2}] {3}", username, domainname, win32ErrorNumber, msg))
        Me.win32ErrorNumber = win32ErrorNumber
    End Sub
End Class

Private Declare Auto Function LogonUser Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal lpszUsername As [String], _
        ByVal lpszDomain As [String], ByVal lpszPassword As [String], _
        ByVal dwLogonType As Integer, ByVal dwLogonProvider As Integer, _
        ByRef phToken As IntPtr) As Boolean


Private Declare Auto Function DuplicateToken Lib "advapi32.dll" (ByVal ExistingTokenHandle As IntPtr, _
            ByVal SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL As Integer, _
            ByRef DuplicateTokenHandle As IntPtr) As Boolean


Private Declare Auto Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal handle As IntPtr) As Boolean

<System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("kernel32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function FormatMessage(ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByRef lpSource As IntPtr, _
      ByVal dwMessageId As Integer, ByVal dwLanguageId As Integer, ByRef lpBuffer As [String], _
      ByVal nSize As Integer, ByRef Arguments As IntPtr) As Integer
End Function

Private Function GetErrorMessage(ByVal errorCode As Integer) As String
    Dim FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER As Integer = &H100
    Dim FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS As Integer = &H200
    Dim FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM As Integer = &H1000

    Dim messageSize As Integer = 255
    Dim lpMsgBuf As String = ""
    Dim dwFlags As Integer = FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER Or FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM Or FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS

    Dim ptrlpSource As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim prtArguments As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero

    Dim retVal As Integer = FormatMessage(dwFlags, ptrlpSource, errorCode, 0, lpMsgBuf, messageSize, prtArguments)
    If 0 = retVal Then
        Throw New System.Exception("Failed to format message for error code " + errorCode.ToString() + ". ")
    End If

    Return lpMsgBuf
End Function
```

End Class
End Class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you actually try to acces the network resource or did you only determine it was not working with the: WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name result ?

The way it works:

Interactive login with default provider works only properly if the user can actually connect to the server. In older Windows version, this was not enforced and could be used instead of the ones below.

Logon_New_Credential (with Winnt50 provider) will impersonate the user for remote connections but will use the original user locally

Logon_Network (with Winnt50 provier) will impersonate you as the desired user locally but the token will fails if you try to initiate a connection remotely.

Therefore, Logon_New_Credential will return your original user if you try WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent.Name in your impersonation loop but will use the impersonated user when accessing the network resource.

See below

[image: Different authentication test]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much Sage Pourpre , it work if i use the first option :

LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT | LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE

Currently i use this type of login, but i will documet because i would like understand the differences.